# Using keywords to find records and list them in a listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I have a form (`frmSearch`) that I use several (4) comboboxes to filter out results for a listbox (`lstCustomers`).  What I'm attempting to do now is create the ability to filter the listbox based on a text box of "keywords". Additionally, the column which the keyword box will search will be variable based on `cboWhere` which is a list of columns from `tblContacts` (the table `qryContactWants` uses)
[image: Picture of the form]


I found a really nice Function set with the following code that will let me filter everything, but I'm not entirely sure how to turn this data around and use it to filter out my listbox.

**This function organizes the keywords:**

```
Public Function FindAnyWord(varFindIn, strWordList As String) As Boolean
Dim var
Dim aWords
    aWords = Split(strWordList, ",")

    For Each var In aWords
        If FindWord(varFindIn, var) Then
            FindAnyWord = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next var          
End Function
```

And this function actually performs the search:

```
    Public Function FindWord(varFindIn As Variant, varWord As Variant) As Boolean

   Const PUNCLIST = """' .,?!:;(){}[]-—/"
   Dim intPos As Integer

   FindWord = False

   If Not IsNull(varFindIn) And Not IsNull(varWord) Then
       intPos = InStr(varFindIn, varWord)

       ' loop until no instances of sought substring found
       Do While intPos > 0
           ' is it at start of string
           If intPos = 1 Then
               ' is it whole string?
               If Len(varFindIn) = Len(varWord) Then
                   FindWord = True
                   Exit Function
               ' is it followed by a space or punctuation mark?
               ElseIf InStr(PUNCLIST, Mid(varFindIn, intPos + Len(varWord), 1)) > 0 Then
                   FindWord = True
                   Exit Function
               End If
           Else
               ' is it precedeed by a space or punctuation mark?
               If InStr(PUNCLIST, Mid(varFindIn, intPos - 1, 1)) > 0 Then
                   ' is it at end of string or followed by a space or punctuation mark?
                   If InStr(PUNCLIST, Mid(varFindIn, intPos + Len(varWord), 1)) > 0 Then
                       FindWord = True
                       Exit Function
                   End If
               End If
           End If

           ' remove characters up to end of first instance
           ' of sought substring before looping
           varFindIn = Mid(varFindIn, intPos + 1)
           intPos = InStr(varFindIn, varWord)
       Loop
   End If

End Function
```

**And here is the code that I typically use to filter the listbox using the comboboxes on `frmSearch`:**

```
   Dim column As String

   SQL = "SELECT qryContactWants.ID, qryContactWants.FullName, qryContactWants.Type, qryContactWants.Make, qryContactWants.Model, qryContactWants.YearWanted, qryContactWants.Condition " _
    & "FROM qryContactWants " _
    & "WHERE 1=1 "
    If cboType.Value & "" <> "" Then
        SQL = SQL & " AND qryContactWants.Type = '" & cboType.Value & "'"
    End If
    If cboMake.Value & "" <> "" Then
        SQL = SQL & " AND qryContactWants.Make = '" & cboMake.Value & "'"
    End If
    If cboModel.Value & "" <> "" Then
        SQL = SQL & " AND qryContactWants.Model = '" & cboModel.Value & "'"
    End If
    If cboYear.Value & "" <> "" Then
        SQL = SQL & " AND qryContactWants.YearWanted = '" & cboYear.Value & "'"
    End If
    If cboCondition.Value & "" <> "" Then
        SQL = SQL & " AND qryContactWants.Condition = '" & cboCondition.Value & "'"
    End If

    SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY qryContactWants.Last"

    Me.lstCustomers.RowSource = SQL
    Me.lstCustomers.Requery
End Sub
```

What I would like to do is take the functions I found for searching keywords and apply it to my form and aid in returning a list of customers in `lstCustomers`
Ideally, having the keyword function return an SQL statement similar to those I'm using to filter out the listbox would be perfect.  This would allow me to add a simple `SQL = SQL & "AND qryContactWants.VARIABLECOLUMNHERE =SOMETHING`

**EDIT 1**:
While using the following code, VBA is tossing a compile error on the second "End If" stating there isn't a Block If.  There clearly is, so I'm not sure what's going on.  Here is the code I'm using:
[image: If Error]

```
Public Function KeyWhere(strKeys As String, strColumn As String) As String

  Dim b As Variant
  strKeys = Replace(strKeys, vbCrLf, ",") ' remove all line returns

  b = Split(strKeys, ",")
  Dim strWhere   As String
  Dim v As Variant
  For Each v In b
     If Trim(b) <> "" Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " or "
         strWhere = strWhere & strColumn & " like '*" & Trim(v) & "*'"
        End If
     End If
  Next
  strWhere = "(" & strWhere & ")"
  KeyWhere = strWhere

End Function
```

And under the function `RequerylistCustomers()` I added the `If IsNull (Me.txtSearch) = False Then` code below:

```
Private Sub RequerylstCustomers()
   Dim SQL As String
   'Dim criteria As String
   Dim column As String

   SQL = "SELECT qryContactWants.ID, qryContactWants.FullName, qryContactWants.Type, qryContactWants.Make, qryContactWants.Model, qryContactWants.YearWanted, qryContactWants.Condition " _
    & "FROM qryContactWants " _
    & "WHERE 1=1 "
    If cboType.Value & "" <> "" Then
        SQL = SQL & " AND qryContactWants.Type = '" & cboType.Value & "'"
    End If
    If cboMake.Value & "" <> "" Then
        SQL = SQL & " AND qryContactWants.Make = '" & cboMake.Value & "'"
    End If
    If cboModel.Value & "" <> "" Then
        SQL = SQL & " AND qryContactWants.Model = '" & cboModel.Value & "'"
    End If
    If cboYear.Value & "" <> "" Then
        SQL = SQL & " AND qryContactWants.YearWanted = '" & cboYear.Value & "'"
    End If
    If cboCondition.Value & "" <> "" Then
        SQL = SQL & " AND qryContactWants.Condition = '" & cboCondition.Value & "'"
    End If

    Dim strWhere   As String
    'Grab Keywords from txtSearch using cboWhere to search for those keywords
    If IsNull(Me.txtSearch) = False Then
        strWhere = KeyWhere(Me.txtSearch, Me.cboWhere)
        SQL = SQL & " AND " & strWhere
    End If

    SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY qryContactWants.Last"


    Me.lstCustomers.RowSource = SQL
    Me.lstCustomers.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps build a string array and use the IN() function: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE fieldname IN('a','b','c');`

Comment: Building on @June7 suggestion, the `strWordList` argument you're passing to `FindAnyWord()` appears to be an ideal candidate for IN function. You could then circumvent the `FindWord()` function

Comment: `If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " or "` is single line and needs no `End If`.

Comment: Fixing that line (@Andre), I get a type mismatch on ```If Trim(b) <> "" Then```

Comment: Should be `Trim(v)`. Remove the extraneous `End If`.

Comment: Thanks @June7 for the edits.  I'm having trouble (see comment under the answer) with the listbox just showing up empty no matter the search criteria I enter.

Comment: Step debug code. Does the function return correct string? I tested function and returned value for me. Debug.Print the constructed SQL string. Run it in a query object. Are records returned?

Comment: With the added pointers to the query, it returns this: ```(qryContactWants.First Name like '*a*')```.  This "seems" right to me.  Without the query pointer, it returns everything minus the ```qryContactWants.```

Comment: Step Debugging turned up nothing.  The function does not return a string, either.  It's odd...I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Are the keywords to be searched in a single column (say a comments or memo column?). If yes, then you should be able to optional "add" the one additional criteria to your current "set" of combo box filters.

Are we to assume that the keywords can appear anywhere in that memo column to search?

So, if there are "key words entered into that text box, then you call KeyWhere.

eg this routine:

```
Public Function KeyWhere(strKeys As String, strColumn As String) As String


  Dim b    As Variant
  strKeys = Replace(strKeys, vbCrLf, ",") ' remove all line returns

  b = Split(strKeys, ",")
  Dim strWhere   As String
  Dim v    As Variant
  For Each v In b
     if trim(v) <> "" then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " or "
        strWhere = strWhere & strColumn & " like '*" & Trim(v) & "*'"
     end if
  Next
  strWhere = "(" & strWhere & ")"
  KeyWhere = strWhere

End Function
```

We assume each key word is separated by a comma (could be space, but comma is better).

So, if I type in the following command in debug window to test the above?

```
?  keywhere("Generator, Water maker, Battery","Notes")
```

OutPut:

```
(Notes like '*Generator*' or Notes like '*Water maker*' or Notes like '*Battery*')
```

So, we just append the above results to your final SQL.

eg:

```
dim strWhere   as string
if isnull(me.KeyWordBox) = False then
  strWhere = keyWhere(me.KeyWordBox,me.cboColumnToSearch)
  SQL = SQL & " AND " & strWhere
end if
```

so, the above converts all keywords into a valid SQL condition for the column to search. It is likely that column is some kind of notes column, but it would work for other  description type field to search.

Comment: This seems plausible for sure, but the code is tossing a compile error at the second "```End If```" saying there isn't an If Block.  There clearly is, so I'm not entirely sure where I went wrong.  I'll post the code I'm using specifically as an edit to the original post.

Comment: Edited to remove the extraneous End If and correct to Trim(v).

Comment: Thanks June - somehow my cut paste or some issue. To the poster: the posted code now should compile.

Comment: We're getting REALLY close - but when I click the command button "Find" to execute the query, the listbox doesn't show any names no matter what I type in it.  For example, I have a contact with the first name "Larry".  So I type "larry" (minus quotes) and select "First Name" from the WHERE combobox and click "Filter".  ```lstCustomers``` goes blank.  Even though there is definitely a customer with the first name Larry.  I tried Larry, larry (case), and even individual letters such as "a" and nothing is populating the list.  However, there aren't any errors, so that's awesome!

Comment: I tried to point it directly to the query itself, too.  Using this line in the function:        ```strWhere = "qryContactWants." & strWhere & strColumn & " like '*" & Trim(v) & "*'" ```