# Find Keywords in "Notes" field and filter Listbox of names based on results

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a textbox (`txtSearch`) that has an `On Change` Event that should filter out a list of names based on keywords the routine finds in a tables `Notes` field.  However, when I  enter text into `txtSearch`, the listbox (`lstCustomers`) doesn't just filter out the results, it wipes them out completely and I get an `(Invalid use of Null)` error.

FYI - I got the routines from another question ([Using keywords to find records and list them in a listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55907652/using-keywords-to-find-records-and-list-them-in-a-listbox)).  I'm moving to a new questions because the client has requested some changes to where the keyword search would be conducted.

[image]

***Here are a few quick details for the routine:***

- *When the user enters text into `txtSearch` it runs the routing `KeyWhere` to create an SQL statement the listbox uses to filter the names.*
- *Debugging `KeyWhere()` in the Immediate window returns a proper statement (**See Image Below**)*

  [image: KeyWhere Results]
- *The `` Run-time error `94`: Invalid use of Null `` occurs on the line `strWhere = KeyWhere(Me.txtSearch, "Notes")`*
- *The "Notes" field in the table is "Long Text"*

***Here is the routine:***

```
Public Function KeyWhere(strKeys As String, strColumn As String) As String

  Dim b    As Variant
  strKeys = Replace(strKeys, vbCrLf, ",") ' remove all line returns

  b = Split(strKeys, ",")
  Dim strWhere   As String
  Dim v    As Variant
  For Each v In b
     If Trim(v) <> "" Then
        If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " or "
        strWhere = strWhere & strColumn & " like '*" & Trim(v) & "*'"
     End If
  Next
  strWhere = "(" & strWhere & ")"
  KeyWhere = strWhere

End Function
```

***And here is the `_Change()` routine:***

```
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT qrySearchDatabase.Notes FROM qrySearchDatabase WHERE 1=1"
    strWhere = KeyWhere(Me.txtSearch.Text, "Notes")
    SQL = SQL & " AND " & strWhere
    Debug.Print SQL

    Me.lstCustomers.RowSource = SQL
    Me.lstCustomers.Requery

End Sub
```

I have a feeling my query (`qrySearchDatabase`) is wonky somehow, but I'm not entirely sure where.  Here is the SQL for my query:

```
SELECT tblContacts.ID, tblContacts.Notes, [Last Name] & ", " & [First Name] AS [File As]
FROM tblContacts
WHERE (((tblContacts.Notes) Is Not Null));
```

**EDIT:** *Updated code based on response below*.
**EDIT 2:** Added image below to show the messed up columns after`Change()`

[image: Weird columns]

Comment: Note that `Me.lstCustomers.Requery` is not necessary after setting the .RowSource (this automatically requeries the listbox).

Comment: Another note: it may feel a little weird if the query runs instantly after each keypress. Usually one uses a little delay, see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51608017/3820271 or

Comment: Once I get this working I'll add in the delay.  Thanks for the advice!  Thanks a LOT!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `_Change` event, the `.Value` property of the textbox isn't yet set.

```
strWhere = KeyWhere(Me.txtSearch, "Notes")
```

`Me.txtSearch` (implicitely) uses `Me.txtSearch.Value`

In the `_Change` event, you must use the `.Text` property instead.

```
strWhere = KeyWhere(Me.txtSearch.Text, "Notes")
```

Comment: That solved the error but the listbox always go empty when typing in a work that I'm 100% positive is listed in a customers note section.  The Debug output is proper, though: ```SELECT Notes FROM qrySearchDatabase WHERE 1=1 AND (Notes like '*W*')
SELECT Notes FROM qrySearchDatabase WHERE 1=1 AND (Notes like '*Wa*')
SELECT Notes FROM qrySearchDatabase WHERE 1=1 AND (Notes like '*Wal*')
SELECT Notes FROM qrySearchDatabase WHERE 1=1 AND (Notes like '*Walk*')```

Comment: It looks like it should work. Try copying the SELECT SQL into a new query in Access, and see if it works there. @BeardedSith

Comment: Yeah, pasting it into a query works.  It returns several results.  But why isn't it updating my listbox based on the customers where the query matches their notes?  I used ```SELECT Notes FROM qrySearchDatabase WHERE 1=1 AND (Notes like '*Walk*')``` and it returned three results (which is the correct amount)

Comment: Here is the query for the listbox initially: ```SELECT qrySearchDatabase.ID, qrySearchDatabase.[File As]
FROM qrySearchDatabase
WHERE (((qrySearchDatabase.Notes) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY qrySearchDatabase.[File As];```

Comment: Aah, your original query has multiple columns, so the listbox has too. The ID column is probably invisible (width = 0), and this is where `Notes` from your dynamic query goes. So your listbox isn't really empty, it just doesn't show the values. You need to always use the same column layout. @BeardedSith

Comment: Got it sorted out, thanks!  ```    SQL = "SELECT ID, FileAs FROM qrySearchDatabase WHERE 1=1"``` instead of pulling Notes.